# On click events are not working on iPad but working on desktop and mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom-events

I'm trying to create simple JavaScript code. I have two buttons with images inside that are used as radio buttons to switch between two options. Everything works great on the most popular types of devices: Android+Chrome, Desktop+Chrome and iPhone+Safari. But when I'm clicking on my iPad+Chrome or iPad+Safari... Nothing happens. And it's not the first time when onclick and similar events/triggers are not working.

I've already tried different events such as `on()` with different options like "click" "tap" "touchstart" and combinations of them, `bind()`, `window.onclick`, `addEventListener` and etc. And they all are working on all platforms I was describing above. But not iPad. Also I've tried advice like "add onclick="" to the element's html code", "add css property cursor: pointer" and another. Here code I'm using now:

```js
window.onload = function () {
    $(document).on('click', 'button.png-option', function () {
        checkIt()
    });
};
```

```html
<button class="png-option" type="button" id="sms-web" onclick="">
                <img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='web.png') }}" class="medium-png active" id="web">
            </button>
```

```css
.png-option {
    height: 50px;
    width: auto;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.medium-png {
    height: 50px;
    width: auto;
}

.medium-png.active {
    border: 4px solid #81bd79;
    border-radius: 25px;
    transition: .2s;
}
```

It's not the first time I meet this issue. The last project I've working had the same issue. And I didn't find any working solution.

Comment: Try changing `$(document).on('click'` to `$(document).on('click touchstart'`. See if that helps.

Comment: I've tried but it didn't...

Comment: In that case you could try `$(document).on('click tap'`. But that's about all I can think of. I don't own an iPad so I'm not able to actually test possible solutions myself.

Comment: Thank you for your advice but it still not working on iPad. Again it works perfect on any another type of device but not iPad...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Connect iPad to Mac machine and check the clickable area. Sometimes, clickable(tap) area may not be in right place or may be area is in collapsed state like 0 width or 0 height. There is also possibility that another invisible layer is above clickable area. Without connecting to Mac machine, it is difficult to debug. Click event should trigger the touch or tap event without fail otherwise.

Comment: Is here any another solution how can I debug it? Or may be Mac simulator? Because I'm working with Windows and Linux currently

Comment: Mac simulator will not help; you need to connect to real Mac machine making developer mode(USB debugging mode) active in iPad. Just like Chrome has developer tools, Safari also has developer tools. So you can debug. Mac simulator does not have features of Mac OS. It can handle only Safari latest browser features to some extent. So can not trust any simulator fully for foolproof results. This is why testers test in real device even though while developing developers use simulators.